# RethinkDB, ReferenceError: connection is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, rethinkdb

I am using `Express.js` and `Rethink` and I am trying to do a simple `post` to a route that saves some info to the database.The initial connection works fine and logs to the console `Connected to Rethink` however, I keep getting `ReferenceError: connection is not defined`when I try to use the connection to `insert` something. Here is the code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var r = require('rethinkdb');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

function dbConnect(){
  var connection = null;
  r.connect({host: 'localhost', port: 28015}, function(err, conn){
    if (err){
      throw err;
    }else{
      connection = conn;
      console.log("Connected to Rethink");
    }
  });
}
dbConnect();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(session({secret: 'gitTy Up!',resave: false,saveUninitialized:true}));
app.use(require('connect-flash')());


app.set('view engine','ejs');

//Home Page
app.get('/', function (req, res) {      
  res.render('home');
})

app.get('/join', function (req, res) {
  res.render('join');
})

app.post('/join',function(req, res){    
  var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
  r.table('users').insert([{email: req.body.email, password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, salt)}])
    .run(connection, function(err,result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
    })
});
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: this is because connection is local, not global in scope

Comment: move your declaration of connection outside of the dbConnect function where you have the rest of your variable declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a scope issue. Connection is local in scope and you're attempting to access it as if it's global. Change:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var r = require('rethinkdb');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

function dbConnect(){
  var connection = null;
  r.connect({host: 'localhost', port: 28015}, function(err, conn){
    if (err){
      throw err;
    }else{
      connection = conn;
      console.log("Connected to Rethink");
    }
  });
}`
```

to

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var r = require('rethinkdb');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var connection = null;
function dbConnect(){

  r.connect({host: 'localhost', port: 28015}, function(err, conn){
    if (err){
      throw err;
    }else{
      connection = conn;
      console.log("Connected to Rethink");
    }
  });
}
```